# cluster points of sequence in intersection set

Tags: sequences-and-series, operator-theory, fixed-point-theorems

For all $n \in \mathbb{N}$, let
$$ x_{n+1} = x_n + \epsilon_n \left( f_n( x_n ) - x_n \right) $$

where $0 < \underline{\epsilon} \leq \epsilon_n \leq 1$, $\ f_n: \mathbb{R}^m \rightarrow C$ is $1$-Lipschitz continuous for all $n$, $C \subset \mathbb{R}^m$ is compact, and $x_0 \in C$.

Suppose that $F = \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \text{fix}(f_n) \neq \emptyset$, and that for all $n$ and $y \in F$:
$$ \left\| x_{n+1}-y\right\|^2 \leq \left\| x_{n}-y\right\|^2 - \rho 
\left\| x_{n} - f_n(x_n)\right\|^2$$
for some $0 < \rho < 1$.

Is it true that all the cluster points of $\left( x_n \right)_n$ are in $F$?

--

What I have done:

0) Observed that, for all $y \in F$, the sequence $\left( \left\| x_n - y\right\| \right)_n$ is bounded and monotonically non-increasing, so it convergences.

1) Shown that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left\| f_n(x_n) - x_n \right\| = 0$.

2) Shown that $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \left\| x_{n+1} - x_n \right\| = 0$.

Comment: Does $y\in F$ mean, that $y=x_m$ with $f_m(x_m)=x_m$ , choosen any $m\in\mathbb{N}$ ?

Comment: For all $n$, define $S_n = \text{fix}(f_n) = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^m : \, x = f_n(x) \}$. Then $y \in F$ means $y \in \bigcap_{n \in \mathbb{N}} S_n $, so $y \in S_n$ for all $n$.